# Android edit fragment elements

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm making an android application with a navigation drawer.

I want this application to connect to the internet, and I need to put a label that contains informations about the connection into a fragment and some buttons to send information in another. I would like the label to update constantly, also if its fragment isn't shown.

My question is:

Is it possible to programmatically edit the elements of a fragment when it isn't shown?

Comment: why you don't pass the data in intent ?, check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Comment: but will this method actually edit my label when I open my fragment?

Answer (score 0):

as an answer to your comment, yes and this is how it works

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "actualValue");
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
// start your fragment
```

and then in your fragment `onCreate` or `onCreateView`

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if(bundle !=null){
   String actualData = bundle.getString("key");
   TextView myTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myText);
   myTextView.setText(actualData);
}
```